# Achieve geosynchronous orbital speeds at leo while moving relative to a electric field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, orbital-motion, superconductivity

Would it be possible for an object to move at geosynchronous orbital speeds at LEO? Assume that a superconductive ring extending around the entire Earth existed at the same height as the ISS. Could an object move relative to the magnetic field instead of gravity? Could the effect of gravity on the object reduce as the magnetic field strength increases? Trying to relate magnetic field and orbital velocity.

$F = qvB \Rightarrow mv^2 / R = qvB$

$R = mv / qB$

$6.778 \cdot 10^6 = (9.1110\cdot 10^{-31}) \cdot (v) / (1.6010 \cdot 10^{19}) \cdot (B)$

Trying to solve for $B$, but stuck on finding $v$. Relating it back to the kinetic energy $qV = \frac {1}{2}mv^2$. Any help on whether I am approaching this incorrectly, or any direction is appreciated!

Comment: Use $R$ as parameter and calculate $v$. For LEO we have $R\le 2000 km$. So put $R=2000 km$.

Comment: I don’t follow what you mean by R as a parameter? Parameter to which equation? Even with R I still have v and B unknown (trying to solve for B)